# How do I make www.example.com/file redirect to www.example.com/file.doc?

Tags: html, apache, redirect, web

How do I make `www.example.com/file` redirect to `www.example.com/file.doc`?

Extra info:

- I am running apache
- I am running an Amazon EC2 instance with ubuntu bitnami-wordpress AMI

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Common rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.doc [L]
```

Your occurrence:

```
RewriteRule ^file$ file.doc [L]
```

Comment: How do I do this? using putty?

Comment: You need to put this code to `.htaccess` file Look [here](http://www.buildwebsite4u.com/advanced/htaccess-file.shtml) for example

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without `mod_rewrite` at all using [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) and Apache httpd's [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html).

But be aware that this has some serious implications for existing rewrite rules.